# How to set a response status for a nuxt page? 404

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, http-status-codes, nuxt3

[image]

I want to set response status 404 on my /not-found page.
I tried to:

1. create custom error page in ~/error.vue and throw fatal errors with `createError`. But it just sends 200
2. throw fatal errors and use [NuxtErrorBoundary](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-error-boundary#nuxterrorboundary). [But it doesn't do anything](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15781)
3. use [setResponseStatus](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/set-response-status#setresponsestatus) in setup

```
const event = useRequestEvent()
setResponseStatus(event, 404)
setResponseStatus(event, 404, 'Page Not Found')
```

But it must be executed (as they say) on the server, so it doesn't always work on setup.

3. Use middleware in `~/server/middleware`):

```
// setResponseStatus wasn't defined in all ~/server/*
// so I had to import it from here 
import { setResponseStatus } from '../../node_modules/nuxt/dist/app'

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  setResponseStatus(event, 404)
})
```

Which either does nothing or just causes `nuxt instance unavailble` error.

It shouldn't so complicated, right? Or what am I missing here?

Currently considering handling 404 in `nginx` instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Using a setup function

```js
<script setup>
if (process.server) {
  const event = useRequestEvent()
  setResponseStatus(event, 404)
}
</script>
```

Since it only works on server you can wrap it in `process.server`.

---

### Using (inline) route middleware

```js
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  middleware: [
    () => {
      const event = useRequestEvent()
      setResponseStatus(event, 404)
    }
  ],
});
</script>
```

Note that you need a route middleware, not a server middleware. Server middleware run on every request which is probably not what you want.

For the sake of simplicity I made the middleware inline but you can have it in the middleware directory.

Comment: Than you, but:
1. 1st method doesn't work cause it's conditional, for me `process.server` is always false (note: ssr: true is used)
2. 2nd doesn't work (I copied and pasted the inline version), it's 200 still. Have you used this method yourself before?

Comment: Sorry, I had a `ssr: false` exception for `/not-found` route. Removed it, but now when I set *any* route the server side has `RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE] Invalid status code: H3Event` error and the whole site lags.

Comment: There might be something breaking the server. Hard to say without looking at the code but my code [works fine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-zpxamz?file=pages%2Fnot-found.vue) for me. How exactly are you setting the route?